# Python: How do I write a program that reads 10 different integers and prints the one that has the largest value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, integer

What is a method, in python, that can be used to read the largest number in a list? My attempt is below:

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
print max(list)
```

EDIT (Solution): Use a for loop.

```
userInput = []
for i in range(10):
    userInput.append(int(input("Enter a number")))
print(max(userInput))
```

Comment: You are making several mistakes here. I suggest taking a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop if you want to do something repeatedly. You want to have an empty list, and then get a number from the user 10 times, so you put all of the requests for a number from the user in a loop. `input` gives you a string, so you need to convert it to an `int`.

```
user_inputs = []

for i in range(10):
    user_inputs.append(int(input("Enter a number")))

print(max(user_inputs))
```

If you don't understand loops, you should look into learning about them.

Comment: `list` is a poor choice for a variable name.

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:python-3.x] so `raw_input` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think along with JHobern, you could probably do something like

`print(max([int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) for x in range(10)]))`

That should do it!
To explain, you know what print and max should do.
raw_input asks the user for an input and stores it.
max() returns the maximum value in a list of things.
[ ______ for x in range(10)] is a list comprehension where it does something 10 times.  Doesn't necessarily use the variable x in this case though.
So basically, I'm using list comprehension to create a list of 10 integers that is provided y the user and then prints out the maximum all in one line :)

Comment: `raw_input()` is not used in Python 3.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ah! woops. sorry about that.  just input() then

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while loop` to achieve this:
This code will prompt the user 10 times to input numbers. Each time the number will be appended to the list `nums`. Also, each time the highest number in `nums` will be printed.

```
nums = []
while len(nums) < 10:
    nums.append(int(input('Enter a number: ')))
    print (max(nums))
```

If you only want to print the highest number at the end, one time, after the 10th input, then you can do this:

```
nums = []
while len(nums) < 10:
    nums.append(int(input('Enter a value: ')))
print (max(nums))
```

You shouldn't use `list` as a variable because `list` is a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

Comment: This will print the maximum value 9 times.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it prints it 10 times

Comment: Which is even worse, it should print it once.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I purposely wanted to print it each time after each input, as I mentioned it in my answer. However, I will make an edit and provide an option to only print it at the end.

Comment: `raw_input()` is not used in Python 3.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks for that, I updated my answer. I am using Python2 and forgot to change it before I posted the answer.